# Adding node with multi value field using Services

Tags: 8, services

While adding node using REST API, submitting multi-value field is adding only one value to that field.

```
{
"title":"test",
"type":"article",
"body":{"und":[{"value":"this is main body"}]},
"field_topic":{"und":[{"value":"topic 1"},{"value":"topic 2"}]}
}
```

the node is created but the field_topic contains only topic 1 and topic 2 is not added.

What is the reason and how to fix that?

Comment: the edit suggestions are great.. answers are also welcomed :)

Comment: What is the type of multi-value field?

Comment: can you please add details about field_topic field.

Comment: The field_topic is a simple Text type field

Comment: Just confirm me, your 'Field Type' is 'Text' and 'Widget' is 'Text field' right?

Comment: Widget type is Text field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15179/discussion-between-krishna-mohan-and-nisar-ahmed).